# Why can't StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync load from an exsisting PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, storagefile

I am trying to pass a PDF generated from a SQL ReportServer back to a UWP application as a PdfDocument. I keep getting an Exception when trying to create the `StorageFile`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("invoicereport/{report}/{invoice}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetInvoiceReport([FromUri] string report, [FromUri] string invoice)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test");

        ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();

        rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        rs.Url = "http://localhost/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx";

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
        var executionInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        executionInfo = rs.LoadReport($"{ReportsDir}/Invoice/{report}", null);
        

        List<ParameterValue> parameters = new List<ParameterValue>();

        parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "SOPNUMBER", Value = invoice });
        parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "SOPTypeString", Value = "Invoice" });

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters.ToArray(), "en-US");

        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string[] streamId;
        Warning[] warning;

        var result = rs.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out encoding, out warning, out streamId);

        FileStream stream = File.Create(System.Web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir + $"/{invoice}.pdf", result.Length);

        //write file with rendered result

        stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);

        //close stream

        stream.Close();

        StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(System.Web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir + $"/{invoice}.pdf").GetResults();

        var pdf = PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file).GetResults();

        return Ok(pdf);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error(ex, "Reporting Error");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

the Exception gets logged as:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1.GetResults()
   at Prism.Web.Queries.Controllers.ReportController.<GetInvoiceReport>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\PointOfSaleBeta\Prism.Web.Queries\Controllers\ReportController.cs:line 183
```

Line 183 corresponds to `StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(System.Web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir + $"/{invoice}.pdf").GetResults();`

I have verified (many times) that the referenced PDF file actually got created. Am I not using the correct syntax for 'GetFileFromPathAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

After I didn't get any answers or comments I tried a different approach. I installed the FreeSpire.PDF nuget package:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("invoicereport/{report}/{invoice}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetInvoiceReport([FromUri] string report, [FromUri] string invoice)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test");

        ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();

        rs.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        rs.Url = "http://localhost/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx";

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
        var executionInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
        executionInfo = rs.LoadReport($"{ReportsDir}/Invoice/{report}", null);
        

        List<ParameterValue> parameters = new List<ParameterValue>();

        parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "SOPNUMBER", Value = invoice });
        parameters.Add(new ParameterValue { Name = "SOPTypeString", Value = "Invoice" });

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters.ToArray(), "en-US");

        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string[] streamId;
        Warning[] warning;

        var result = rs.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out encoding, out warning, out streamId);

        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

        pdf.LoadFromBytes(result);

        

        return Ok(pdf);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error(ex, "Reporting Error");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

This solved (worked around) my problem.